# Play Sound on click of Launcher Icon

Tags: android, app-launcher

I have a requirement where upon clicking the launcher icon of my app, it should read out the app name.

I know it's a kind of funny, but is that possible? any directions?

Comment: don't think this is possible due to the sandbox model of an Android application, not 100 % sure

Comment: The upper mentioned feature will break the expected user experience and your users won't appreciate it.

Comment: This is not recommended but you can actually play the sound file in onCreate of Launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the onCreate/onResume method of your activity: [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Just start the player

`mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.reset();

    mp.setDataSource(fileNamePath);

    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();`